# Extracting keys and values from a string

Tags: python, regex, split

this is probably very easy but I feel I am doing it wrong.
Let's say I have the following string:

```
user: bob status: married age:45
```

Now I want to break it down to something like:

```
user = 'bob'
status ='married'
age = 45
```

At the moment I am doing a lot of dirty splitting work but there's gotta be a better, Pythonic way using Regex.
Here's what I do:

```
full_text = 'user: bob status: married age:45'
type = 'user'        
cut_string = full_text_string.split(type + ":", 1)[1].split(" ")[0]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use something like `re.findall(r'(\w+):((?:(?!\w+:).)*)', s)`

Comment: Shouldn't there be space between `:` and `45` as well?

Comment: Oh wow, that's very nice Wiktor. But can you please explain what it does? I'd like to learn this magic trick

Comment: I think Patrick's should also work. If not I will post mine.

Comment: @PavelZagalsky for future, https://regex101.com/, incl. python interpreter

Comment: Maybe you should be using a dictionary to store the keys and values

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution.  The regex : [`(\w+)\s*:\s*((?:\w+\b\s*)+)(?!\s*:)`](https://regex101.com/r/1iGlz6/1)

```
import re 

s = 'user: bob status: married with children age:45'

pat = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*((?:\w+\b\s*)+)(?!\s*:)')

print(pat.findall(s))
```

prints

```
[('user', 'bob '), ('status', 'married with children '), ('age', '45')]
```

You can then use something like `ast.literal_eval` to get the types right

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall(r'(?:([0-9a-zA-Z]+): ?([0-9a-zA-Z]+))+',s)`

This will give back: `[('user', 'bob'), ('status', 'married'), ('age', '45')]`

The first group is a non-capturing group it means that this won't be in the results of findall.

The `[0-9a-z-A-Z]` part is equivalent to `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who avoid regex if we possibly can:

```
>>> full_text='user: bob status: married age:45'
>>> alt_text = full_text.replace(':',' ').split()
>>> print alt_text[0],"=",alt_text[1]
>>> print alt_text[2],"=",alt_text[3]
>>> print alt_text[4],"=",alt_text[5]
user = bob
status = married
age = 45
```

If you had a space between `age:` and `45` you wouldn't have to use `replace` just `full_text.split()` would suffice.